# How to load table from file

Tags: lua, lua-table

I know how to write table content in a text file and restore it. But what is the best practice to write a custom table type in a file?

Here is my situation:
I have a list of tables f.e. `objective1 = {} objective2 = {} objective3 = {}` ..
Each objective has its own execute function which checks some conditions and execute some commands depending on the conditions.
Each new game a pick a random set of objectives and store them in an array `Objectives = { [1] = { objective1 , objective3 } }`
Now I want to save the array of random objectives and load them later from the file.

Is there any possibility to save the name of the tables in the array and to restore them  by the name?
Would be great to have a solution without using a factory pattern or using indices for saving.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the data in the table is not a `userdata` (for eg. a SQL or socket connection, or other libraries) you can use [the pickle module](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PickleTable) to write the data to a file and later load the same from there.

I personally use a different [pickle library](https://github.com/hjpotter92/ptokax-scripts/blob/master/files/dependency/pickle.lua) (written by **Walter Doekes**). The usage is as follows:

```
local TableToStore = { 'a', 'b', 1, {'nested', 'content', {c = 'inside'}} }
pickle.store( 'backupFileName.bak', {TableToStore = TableToStore} )
```

and to restore the data, I can simply use

```
dofile "backupFileName.bak"
```

and I'll get back a table named `TableToStore` after this.

Comment: It is probably worth pointing out that unless your application is sandboxed or you are externally verifying your input indiscriminately calling `dofile`/`loadstring + pcall` opens you up to a good number of security issues (and this is without talking about the bytecode attacks that caused the verifier drop for 5.2).